# Remote XML Datasource in JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource, jasperserver

My report has a "remote xml file datasource". It works fine in *iReport*, but there is no such datasource type in *JasperReport Server*. Only JDBC, mongoDB and so on.

Is there a way of using "remote xml file datasource" on *JasperReports Server*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. You probably have to upload the file directly to the directory on the server, rather than through the browser.

Comment: Where are these files located?